# CAML query to select data in specfic range

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

CAML query to select data in specfic range.

I have a list-A and it has a column 'Col1' which has thousands records, I want to fetch data in a specific range as:

select Col1,Col2 from list-A where Col1 > 100 and Col1 < 600

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Geq and Leq, here I left you an example:

```
    <Query><Where>
    <And>
    <Geq><FieldRef Name="StartDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">201412-01T10:23:51Z</Value></Geq>
    <Leq><FieldRef Name="DueDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2014-12-01T10:24:09Z</Value></Leq>
    </And>
    </Where></Query>
```

Good Look :)